# Попытка занести в бд данные

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Есть форма, в который какое-то количество селектов. 
Так же, прикручен плагин dropzone.js

В данный момент, при нажатии на кнопку, получается заставить делать только одно действие, либо загрузить файл(закидывает его в папку, а в бд только путь), либо отправить данные из форм в БД.

Возможно ли совместить эти действия на одну кнопку?

Если делать так, то не срабатывает загрузка файла.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  url: 'upload.php',
  init: function () {

      var myDropzone = this;

      // Update selector to match your button
      $("#btn").onclick(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          myDropzone.processQueue();
          $.ajax({
            url: "../add_article.php"
          });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Совместить возможно. Но у вас не хватает конкретики в вопросе.

Comment: а что конкретно нужно? нужно запаралелить оба действия, чтоб добавилось в бд

Comment: @NorthNorthern конкретно непонятно в чём ваша проблема. Нужно что бы два действия совершались одновременно? Ну так берите , отлавливайте событие нажатия на кнопку и перечисляйте 1, 2, 3, N действий которые вам нужно выполнить. Такой ответ вас устроит?

Comment: @RomanAndreev мне не понятно каким образом это можно реализовать, если одно действие, это просто подтверждение загрузки через js, а второе insert в бд.

Comment: @NorthNorthern , $('#selector).onclick(function() { //код загрузки файла; $.ajax({ //код обращения к php-скрипту в котором вы делаете insert в бд})
В общем случае вот так. Если нужно более конкретно - обозначьте задачу конкретнее и приведите примеры кода.

Comment: @RomanAndreev Разобрался, спасибо)

Comment: @RomanAndreev не помогло( добавил кусок кода в пост. Если мало, докину еще